# Column polar charts across different layers in a stage-based layout - possible?

Tags: javascript, anychart

I was wondering if a stage-based layout using layers also works with column polar charts.
I’ve been trying to but with no success.

Below is the piece of code I am working on which only displays the buttons I'd like to have at the top to toggle over different charts.
I'd like to have the same column polar chart (but with different data) replicated for the other buttons.

Thanks in advance to anyone providing support here!
Andrew

Code:

```
<div id="anychart-embed-ZYGqlpO0" class="anychart-embed anychart-embed-ZYGqlpO0">
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-base.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-exports.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/js/anychart-polar.min.js"></script>
<div id="ac_style_ZYGqlpO0" style="display:none;">
html,
body,
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
button {
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
</div>
<script>(function(){
function ac_add_to_head(el){
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.insertBefore(el,head.firstChild);
}
function ac_add_link(url){
var el = document.createElement('link');
el.rel='stylesheet';el.type='text/css';el.media='all';el.href=url;
ac_add_to_head(el);
}
function ac_add_style(css){
var ac_style = document.createElement('style');
if (ac_style.styleSheet) ac_style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
else ac_style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
ac_add_to_head(ac_style);
}
ac_add_link('https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/css/anychart-ui.min.css');
ac_add_link('https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/v8/fonts/css/anychart-font.min.css');
ac_add_style(document.getElementById("ac_style_ZYGqlpO0").innerHTML);
ac_add_style(".anychart-embed-ZYGqlpO0{width:600px;height:450px;}");
})();</script>
<button onclick="Overall summary()">Overall summary</button>
<button onclick="AAA()">AAAAA</button>
<button onclick="BBB()">BBBBB</button>
<button onclick="CCC()">CCCCC</button>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
anychart.onDocumentReady(function () {
  // create polar chart
  var chart = anychart.polar();

  var columnSeries1 = chart.column([
    { x: 'Aaaaaa', value: 5.2 },
    { x: 'Bbbbbb', value: 5 },
    { x: 'Cccccc', value: 5.6 },
    { x: 'Dddddd', value: 4.4 },
    { x: 'Eeeeee', value: 4.9 },
    { x: 'Ffffff', value: 3.9 }
  ]);
 
    // set series name
  columnSeries1.name('2023');
 
    var columnSeries2 = chart.column([
    { x: 'Aaaaaa', value: 4 },
    { x: 'Bbbbbb', value: 4.3 },
    { x: 'Cccccc', value: 5.2 },
    { x: 'Dddddd', value: 3.7 },
    { x: 'Eeeeee', value: 4.6 },
    { x: 'Ffffff', value: 3.9 }
  ]);

  // set series name
  columnSeries2.name('2018');

      var columnSeries3 = chart.column([
    { x: 'Aaaaaa', value: 4.4 },
    { x: 'Bbbbbb', value: 4.2 },
    { x: 'Cccccc', value: 5 },
    { x: 'Dddddd', value: 3.5 },
    { x: 'Eeeeee', value: 4 },
    { x: 'Ffffff', value: 0 }
  ]);

  // set series name
  columnSeries3.name('2015');
 
  // adjust chart settings
  var title = chart.title();
  // enable title
  title.enabled(true);
  // set padding
  title.padding(5);
  // set title text
  title.text("Xxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyy");
  title.fontSize(20).fontColor('black');
  // settings for title background
  var titleBackground = chart.title().background();
  // enable background
  titleBackground.enabled(true);
  // set background inner color
  titleBackground.fill("#FFD700");
  // set background border
  titleBackground.stroke("#D8D8D8");
  // set type of background corners
  titleBackground.cornerType("round");
  // set corners size
  titleBackground.corners(10);

  // enable sorting points by x
  chart.sortPointsByX(true);
 
  // disable y-axis
  chart.yAxis(false);

  // set value prefix for tooltip
  chart.tooltip().valuePrefix('Score:');

  // set x-scale
  chart.xScale('ordinal');

  // set chart container id
  chart.container('container');
 
  // create the legend
  chart.legend().enabled(true).itemsLayout('vertical').position('right').fontColor('black');
 
  // configure the chart labels
  var labels = chart.xAxis().labels();
  labels.fontSize(20)
    .fontColor('black');
 
    // customize the series color
    columnSeries1.color('#83B8AE');
    columnSeries2.color('#DC911B');
    columnSeries3.color('#DDD65A');
 
    chart.padding(50, 0, 0, 0);

    // initiate chart drawing
    chart.draw();
});
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to toggle different data to appear on the chart. 
We recommend utilizing only one instance of a chart and the same series.

You can find more information about it on the [data manipulation documentation page](https://docs.anychart.com/Working_with_Data/Overview)

Please, explore the [Playground Demo with a data change toggle](https://playground.anychart.com/GhlORiEE)

Data for the series sets from a variable. 
This provides an opportunity to reuse this data further.

```
  var columnSeries1 = chart.column(actualData1);
  // set series name
  columnSeries1.name('2023');
```

*Lines 61-71*

To show different data, it is possible to change the existing series data.
Switching data is implemented in the following functions.

```
//function for switching to "Overall summary"
  var summary = function(){
    columnSeries1.data(actualData1);
    columnSeries2.data(actualData2);
    columnSeries3.data(actualData3);
  }
```

*Lines 129-140*

In the implemented solution, button listeners are set in the JS code, not in the HTML.
This approach provides more flexibility.

```
  //register a click on a button and fire according function
  document.getElementById("overall").addEventListener("click", summary);
  document.getElementById("alignment").addEventListener("click", alignment)
```

*Lines 142-144*